# SQL join with prefix on the ON value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables, `t1` contains `email` and `phone`. `t2` contains `prefixEmail`. `prefixEmail` is an email address with a campaign code as prefix, example: `'4382_john@test.com'` or `'christmas15_john@test.com'`.

I want to do the following join (pseudo code):

```
SELECT 't1.email', 't1.phone' 
FROM t1
JOIN t2
WHERE t1.email LIKE '%t2.prefixEmail%'.
```

The result should be a table with email and phone to john@test.com, but sarah@test.com should not be included in the result since she is not in t2.prefixEmail.

Summary: How can I make a JOIN where the email in t1 is a part of a value in t2?

Comment: 't1.email' is a string.

Answer (score 1):

By putting `t2.prefixEmail` inside the `'`s, you are treating it as a string literal. Instead, you could concat the `%`s on both its sides:

```
SELECT t1.email, t1.phone
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.email LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.prefixEmail, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 't1.email', 't1.phone' 
FROM
  t1 JOIN t2
  ON t1.email LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(t2.prefixEmail, '%', '\%'), '%')
```